# Microsoft Sync Framework Toolkit iPhone example - date format wrong?

Tags: ios, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I am currently having trouble with upload in the sample - doesn't work with below error message "Invalid Date Time value received."

It seem to be complaining about how the date is formatted as string - `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SS` is how the iPhone sample code originally formatted it to, changed it to `yy-mm-ddTHH:mm:ss:SSS` as said in HTML5 example inline documentation, and few other formats, but no luck.

What is the correct format?

---

Here're what I've done to get the sample to work for download part...

As instructed, I have changed the URI in plist file.

Looking at HTML5 example, I realized the URL for webservice was in wrong format, so changed them  as below..

```
 //self.uploadURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/DefaultScopeSyncService.svc/?syncScope=DefaultScope&operation=UploadChanges&userid=%@", self.baseURL, [anc valueForKey:@"userID"]]];
 self.uploadURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/DefaultScopeSyncService.svc/defaultscope/UploadChanges?userid=%@", self.baseURL, [anc valueForKey:@"userID"]]];     

 //self.downloadURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/DefaultScopeSyncService.svc/?syncScope=DefaultScope&operation=DownloadChanges&userid=%@", self.baseURL, [anc valueForKey:@"userID"]]];
 self.downloadURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/DefaultScopeSyncService.svc/defaultscope/DownloadChanges?userid=%@", self.baseURL, anc.userID]];
```

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone else...

Found the format that works.  `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS`
The time format conversion seem to be done in Formatters/FormatterUtilities.cs file